# mysql query returning wrong results

Tags: mysql

Background...

I'm trying to query the database to see what rental properties we have available in a given date range.  The storage method is horrible, but it's being created by a desktop program :/
The website is written in Wordpress, but I can't even get the correct results even when I manually query the database.

The Problem...
There are 3 columns in the database: `propid`, `av_date` and `avail`.  I have a property that is booked on May 31st and June 8th, but available every day between.  When I view the data in the table, it looks like this:

```
propid   av_date     avail

1051     2013-05-31  U
1051     2013-06-01  A
1051     2013-06-02  A
1051     2013-06-03  A
1051     2013-06-04  A
1051     2013-06-05  A
1051     2013-06-06  A
1051     2013-06-07  A
1051     2013-06-08  U
```

When I run the following query, the property is still showing up...

```
SELECT DISTINCT propid
FROM availabilities
WHERE avail = 'A'
AND av_date IN ('2013-05-31', '2013-06-01', '2013-06-02', '2013-06-03', '2013-06-04', '2013-06-05', '2013-06-06', '2013-06-07', '2013-06-08');
```

I've been beating my head against the wall for 2 days over this, so it's probably something stupid, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what's your expected result?

Comment: "av_date IN (....)" Only needs one hit to pass as true. Thats where to problem is..

Comment: What do you mean by "the property is still showing up"? I'd expect your query to get all the rows where `avail = 'A'` *and* `av_date` is in the list of dates. For your sample data, that happens to be all the rows with `avail = 'A'`. What result do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exclude the property entirely if it has an `avail = 'U'` in the date range, try counting for occurrences of `U` and omitting any that have at least one `U`:

```
SELECT propid
FROM availabilities
WHERE av_date IN ('2013-05-31', '2013-06-01', '2013-06-02', '2013-06-03', '2013-06-04', '2013-06-05', '2013-06-06', '2013-06-07', '2013-06-08')
GROUP BY propid
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN avail = 'U' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

And finally, you can use a range for the dates with `BETWEEN`, which makes the query shorter and easier to maintain:

```
SELECT propid
FROM availabilities
WHERE av_date BETWEEN '2013-05-31' AND '2013-06-08'
GROUP BY propid
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN avail = 'U' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Comment: That's what I was missing! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT propid, avail, av_date
FROM availabilities
GROUP BY propid HAVING avail = 'A'
AND av_date IN ('2013-05-31', '2013-06-01', '2013-06-02', '2013-06-03', '2013-06-04', '2013-06-05', '2013-06-06', '2013-06-07', '2013-06-08');
```

Comment: `select distinct` with a single field is functionally identical to normal query grouping on that field. you've changed nothing except the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude propids with any unavailability by using NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.propid 
FROM availabilities a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
( SELECT 1
FROM availabilities b
WHERE b.avail = 'U' 
AND b.propid = a.propid 
AND b.av_date IN ('2013-05-31', '2013-06-01', '2013-06-02', '2013-06-03', '2013-06-04', '2013-06-05', '2013-06-06', '2013-06-07', '2013-06-08');
)
```

The subquery can include conditions based on values from availabilities a.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is finding properties that are available on *any* of the dates.  To get all the dates, you have a set-within-sets question.  I find the best approach is aggregation with a `having` clause.

```
SELECT propid
FROM availabilities
group by propid
having sum(case when av_date IN ('2013-05-31', '2013-06-01', '2013-06-02', '2013-06-03', '2013-06-04', '2013-06-05', '2013-06-06', '2013-06-07', '2013-06-08') and
                     avail <> 'A'
                then 1
                else 0
           end) > 0
```

The `having` clause counts the number of rows where the condition is *not* true.  If there are any, then the property is not included.  You can also approach this as:

```
SELECT propid
FROM availabilities
group by propid
having sum(case when av_date IN ('2013-05-31', '2013-06-01', '2013-06-02', '2013-06-03', '2013-06-04', '2013-06-05', '2013-06-06', '2013-06-07', '2013-06-08') and
                     avail = 'A'
                then 1
                else 0
           end) = 9;
```

The `9` is the number of dates in your set.